# route user when browser is refreshed (socket.io)

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, angular-socket-io

Hello how can i route the user when the browser is refreshed? before refreshing the user is connected to the node server via socket.io. I want the user to route to home page then cut its connection.

```
socket.on('disconnect' , function(){

})
```

the disconnect event seems not to be firing.
A help would be so much appreciated. Thank you so much.